# Why import store undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to get state from store for setting default token axios when I `console.log` and then I found `undefined`.

[image: this is image about folder structure]

This my code axiosConfig.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import _ from 'lodash'
const BASE_URL = '********.com'
import store from '../store'
console.log('store', store)

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

export { instance }
```

this my code store.js:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga'
import rootSaga from './sagas'
import rootReducer from './reducers/index'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'
import logger from 'redux-logger'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

export const defaultState = {}

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware()

const store = createStore(rootReducer, defaultState, applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)))

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

export default store
```

Error:

```
store undefined
```

Comment: can you show the folder structure ? are you sure the store path is correct ?

Comment: yes i can, now i show folder structure image

Comment: Assuming the export doesn't end up being undefined (I assume it doesn't), it could be a circular import problem.  It is very difficult to say as the entire set of code concerned is not here.  Ensure the `store` file is executed before the `axios` file is executed.  My guess, something (maybe in your sagas?) imports the `axios` instance file (`api.js`?).  That would mean `store -> sagas -> axios -> store`.  This is just a guess as, there is not enough code here to determine the problem.

Comment: Try `./store.js`

Comment: @Goblinlord Can you show the practice for solving this problem

Comment: i try ./store.js  and hten error message Can't resolve './store' in

Comment: What file is that? The one with the `import store` statement?

Comment: `../store` is correct based on the folder structure in the image.  As a note, `import` statements should always be at the top (there should not be a `const` declaration between import statements.  This has nothing to do with your issue though (or shouldn't).

Comment: In order to prove that is the problem, you can comment out all imports in `store.js` and then just export an object or variable (like a string or number or anything other than `undefined`).  Then determine if it is still undefined or not in the file where you are exporting an `axios` instance.  My guess though, is that it is imported in a `saga`... so if you remove the `saga` import, I am guessing it just won't even be run.  Anyways... you need to find the circular dependency and change it to not have a circular dependency (if you find that is actually the problem).